# Sup and Inequalities

Tags: real-analysis

In the following excerpt from a textbook:

> Th. If $A$ is compact, then it is bounded.

> Pr. Let $E = \{B(p, 1)\}_{{p \in A}}$
> Since $A$ is compact there exists a finite subcover $J$ composed of unit neighbourhoods centered on a finite (and therefore bounded) set of points $P$.
> Take $x, y \in A$, by the definition of our cover, $\exists p_{i}, p_{j} \in P : d(x, p_{i}) < 1, d(y, p_{j}) < 1$
> Therefore, $d(x,y) \leq d(x, p_{i}) + d(p_{i}, p_{j}) + d(p_{j}, y) < d(p_{i}, p_{j}) + 2$
> $\sup d(x,y) = \text{diam} A \leq \text{diam} P + 2$

I don't understand how taking the sup makes the strict inequality, non-strict, shouldn't the final result be $\sup d(x,y) = \text{diam} A < \text{diam} P + 2$?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. If you have a bounded set $S$ of real numbers and if, for some number $M$, you have $x<M$ for each $x\in S$, then $\sup S\leqslant M$, but it is not necessarily true that $\sup S<M$. Take, for instance $S=(0,1)$ and $M=1$.

On your proof, suppose that $A=(-1,2)$ (with the usual distance) and that $P=\left\{0,1\right\}$. If $x,y\in A$, then the distance from $x$ to some element of $P$ is smaller than $1$, and the same thing is true for $y$. So, $d(x,y)<d\left(0,1\right)+2=3$. But $\operatorname{diam}(A)\,\color{red}{\mathbf=}\,3$.

Comment: Yeah, I just realised this is the case since $\sup A$ does not have to be a member of $A$. Thanks